# JPA: OneToMany Bidirectional mapping has an issue - detached entity passed to persist:

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-ee-6

I googled this issue, and tried to find out on stack overflow as well but didn't find the solution.

here is @OneToMany relationship defined

```
    Order.java
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "order", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

    private Set<OrderLine> orderLines = new HashSet<>();

//Setter method
    public void setOrderLines(Set<OrderLine> orderLines) {
        orderLines.forEach(orderLine -> orderLine.setOrder(this));
        this.orderLines = orderLines;
    }
```

******    OrderLine.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "orderId")
private Order order;

public void setOrder(Order order) {
    this.order = order;
}
```

Here is my save method in service

```
public ResponseEntity<OrderDTO> save(OrderDTO orderDTO) {
    OrderDTO returnODTO = null;
    Order order = modelMapper.map(orderDTO, Order.class);
    order.setOrderStatus(OrderStatus.CREATED);
    Order save = orderRepo.save(order);
    if (save != null)
        returnODTO = modelMapper.map(save, OrderDTO.class);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(returnODTO, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

I have repo for Order.java

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepo extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

}
```

I am posting the below JSON

```
{
    "orderId": 1,
    "customerId": 133,
    "createdOn": null,
    "updatedOn": null,
    "deliveredOn": null,
    "orderLines": [
        {
            "orderLineId": 1,
            "itemId": 1213,
            "qty": 13.0
        }
    ],
    "orderStatus": null
}
```

This is the error am getting

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-07T05:56:28.769+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "detached entity passed to persist: org.hams.orderservice.domain.OrderLine; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.hams.orderservice.domain.OrderLine",
    "trace": "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: org.hams.orderservice.domain.OrderLine; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.hams.orderservice.domain.OrderLine\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:319)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.save(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.hams.orderservice.service.OrderService.save(OrderService.java:42)\r\n\tat org.hams.orderservice.service.OrderService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7f3d06a2.invoke(<generated>)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)\r\n\tat org.hams.orderservice.service.OrderService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c7ade463.save(<generated>)\r\n\tat org.hams.orderservice.controller.OrderController.createOrder(OrderController.java:40)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\r\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.hams.orderservice.domain.OrderLine\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:734)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:702)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$7.cascade(CascadingActions.java:298)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:492)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:416)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:525)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:456)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:419)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:218)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:151)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:459)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:293)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:123)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:710)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:696)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.persist(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.persist(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)\r\n\t... 67 more\r\n",
    "path": "/orderservice/orders/"
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit and send the mapper function which you used to set OrderDTO. Need to See where you are saving OrderLine object. As per the error OrderLine is currently in detached state.

Comment: Its a build in function of ModelMapper class. I have added this dependency for this.
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
   <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.5</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The saving process using JPA Id is not required, it required Update Method.
When you provide Id, JPA tries to update this Object and there is no object belong to the database with this id what is you provide then Jpa throw this Error.

**Remove Id and try Like this:**

```
        {
            "customerId": 133,
            "createdOn": null,
            "updatedOn": null,
            "deliveredOn": null,
            "orderLines": [
                {
                    "itemId": 1213,
                    "qty": 13.0
                }
            ],
            "orderStatus": null
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, anyhow am ignoring this property at Java Side,

 @JsonIgnore
 private Long orderId;

Comment: Silly mistakes, Bro it worked. Thank you very much. I was ignoring only order-id not order-line-id. Thanks